# Performing SSL request in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlsession, google-translate

I'm trying to use the Google Translate API for a simple iOS app I'm building. I'm essentially stuck in trying to use SSL for this request.

According to [Google Translate API, it supports SSL](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq). So now my question is how do I even do this? Here's some code that I'm trying right now. I have an API from the translate API.

```
func translateRequest(text: String, fromLang: String, toLang: String) {
    let httpsURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=<MYAPIKEYHERE>&source=\(fromLang)&target=\(toLang)&q=\(text)&format=text")
    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = NSTimeInterval(10)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let translateTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(httpsURL!, completionHandler: completionHandlerTranslate)
    translateTask.resume()
}

func completionHandlerTranslate(dataOpt: NSData?, responseOpt: NSURLResponse?, errorOpt: NSError?) {
    // A helper function to do something with responses
}
```

Now since I'm using `NSURLSession` (instead of `NSURLConnection`), I'm also having my controller by the `NSURLSessionDelegate`. According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH8-SW1) (in the Configuring Authentication section), for `NSURLSession` I only need to implement `didReceiveChallenge` function. The signature of the function is:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

}
```

But I have no idea what should go in there. I've seen a lot of examples of folks trying to verify the server etc, but I'm still confused.

Here are my questions:

1. SSL is used to encrypt data, so what do I need to do in `didReceiveChallenge` for encrypted communication to happen between client and server?
2. How can I make sure that `didReceiveChallenge` rejects all other certificates (like placing a proxy like CharlesProxy and trying to sniff the data)?

Comment: Just to be clear, if SSL (i.e. TLS 1.2) is used, you don't have to do anything to encrypt the communication. It is encrypted. You're only seeing in it Charles because you've used administrator privileges to enable SSL proxying. But in terms of making sure someone can't do even that, you might try posting the question to http://security.stackexchange.com, as you might reach people more familiar with these issues...

Answer (score 0):

It usually isn't a good idea to prevent use of Charles Proxy, because it isn't practical for someone to use it against someone else.  It only works because the user has explicitly installed certificates to tell the OS to trust the fake certs that Charles Proxy produces.  Users generally like the ability to see what data your app is sending on their own devices, and preventing them from doing so will probably create the impression that your app is doing something shady.

With that said, if you *really* want to prevent HTTPS proxies from working, the way you would do that is with **key pinning**.  Instead of trusting the certificate, you write a didReceiveChallenge handler that requests default handling for everything except for server trust.  Then, for server trust:

- Extract the proposed credential from the challenge object.
- Extract the first (leaf) certificate from the credential's certificate chain; IIRC, this is at index 0, but don't quote me on that.
- Extract the public key from the certificate.
- Add a copy of your server's public key in your app bundle somewhere.
- Compare the two public keys.  If they match, return/call the callback in such a way that tells it to use the provided certificate.
- If they don't match, cancel the entire connection/task.

That's the basic idea, anyway.  With that change, the only way to sniff the traffic is to replace the public key in your app bundle and re-sign the app.